# Deleting Windows stuff

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, bootloader, architecture

I currently have a dual boot with Ubuntu LTS and Windows 7 on different partitions and want to remove the dual boot.
The thing is, I don't have free space on my hard disk and I am currently unable to arrange for external backup media. So what I want to do is to just delete the Windows specific folders in the "C drive" and leave my data as it is. And then manually tell grub to forget about Windows and the dual boot. I will delete Windows stuff on the partition but I don't know how to configure grub.
I don't have any backup media available that's why I asked this as a separate question. I just wanted to know whether this approach is reasonable and needed help on modifying grub.

Also, I have 32 bit Ubuntu currently installed, and my system does support 64 bit. So how can I migrate to 64 bit without losing any data and programs? Isn't it possible to just use the same username and password and data would be restored?

Comment: My situation is a bit different. I read that question before posting. I need to save some stuff on that partition and I don't have large amounts of empty space on other partitions.

Comment: So you want to remove boot data of windows and then delete windows files without formatting. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I just want to delete the Microsoft folders from Nautilus and then tell grub that this machine is no longer dual booting. Deleting the partition method won't work for me as I have no backup devices.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution for your problem, but I highly recommend you to backup your important data before testing any solutions. Consider using online services like dropbox or box.net .

Comment: Yeah I wil backup the very essential stuff online. But still I believe that in theory this sounds like a good method. I mean I don't see any reason as to why it won't work.

Comment: Have you tried steps in "Further Operations > Edit GRUB" part in the following link?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

Comment: Yeah that seems helpful. Let me try and report back.

Comment: Whether your system is single or dual boot is a matter of human perception. You "tell grub that this machine is no longer dual booting" by modifying the grub config file. For example with Grub Customizer. The easiest would be to set Ubuntu as default entry and set the timeout to 0. You can even decide to let the Windows entry remain, as it will not be used anyway.